# How to draw squiggly lines with Flutter

Tags: flutter, material-ui

I am looking to draw a shape that is a squiggly line to divide text.

Please can someone give me some guidance on how I would go about doing this?

Here is what I'd like to create: [image: What I'd like to create]

Any help wiould be much appreciated..

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for paths , a tool that allows you to create shapes and lines and "freestyle" with them. [This guide](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0) explains the shapes that different methods create, and [this more advanced article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/playing-with-paths-in-flutter-97198ba046c8) that introduces math and trigonometry.

I did not find a specific resolution for your problem, but these are great guides on what to do. If I am able to reproduce the result you are looking for, I'll post the code.